# How do I prove that $\alpha/\lVert\alpha\rVert$ is differentiable?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\alpha\colon I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a $C^2$-curve such that $\alpha(t)\neq 0$.

How do I prove that $\alpha/\lVert\alpha\lVert$ is differentiable?

Comment: It should be said that $\alpha(t)\neq 0$

Comment: Oh i will edit it.

Comment: It is a composition of differentiable functions (in particular because $\alpha(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$).

Comment: Now, Show that $f:R^3\to R^3$ by $\alpha\mapsto \dfrac{\alpha}{|\alpha|} $ is differantable.

Comment: @mesel I have a trouble with that one.. I want to find the Fréchet derivative explicitly

Comment: @Rubertos Well, just calculate it using $\|\alpha\|'=\frac{\langle\alpha,\alpha'\rangle}{\|\alpha\|^2}$.

Comment: @Michael Is it square? Isn't it just $||\alpha||$?

Comment: @Rubertos You're right, it's just $\|\alpha\|$, so the derivative of $\\alpha/\|\alpha\|$ is easily calculated.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe would you please write that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative is according to my comment
$$\frac{\alpha'\|\alpha\|-\alpha\frac{\langle\alpha,\alpha'\rangle}{\|\alpha\|}}{\|\alpha\|^2}=\frac{\alpha'\|\alpha\|^2-\alpha\langle\alpha,\alpha'\rangle}{\|\alpha\|^3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $ \alpha : I\to \mathbb{R}^3 $ then we can write $ \alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t)) $ and $$ ||\alpha||_{(t)} = \sqrt{x_{(t)}^2+y_{(t)}^2+z_{(t)}^2}$$ witch is a differentiable because the square root is never $0$ (it is given by the fact that $||\alpha||\neq 0$).
Division of differentiable functions is differentiable (if the denominator is never zero), so $ \frac{\alpha}{||\alpha||} $ is differentiable. QED